# With a plaintext file, is it okay to replace a read/write with an append?

Tags: python, file

I am following the Ardit Sulce's Python course in Udemy. While he teaches to work with the .txt files in Python he wrote that code for not to delete the older data in .txt file:

```
file = open('todox.txt', 'r')
todos = file.readlines()
file.close()

todos.append(todo)

file=open('todox.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(todos)
file.close()
```

while I was looking for a better way for that I found this in help(open):

```
'a'       open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
```

and I thought that instead of using the read and the write part two times using append will be much more easier than the way that tutor showed. Is there any potential that my idea could break up my code?

Comment: Do you actually need to read the existing data prior to appending to it?  If so, you might look at `"r+"` as a mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'a' will work better for this use case, however if you wish to read and write on top of this appending behaviour, it may save code to use the example.

```
file = open('todox.txt', 'a')
file.write(todo)
file.close()
```

the only difference this will make is that you haven't read the content into the todos array like in the example, and if you wish to use this array for anything anywhere else, then the example is better.